# Select the first ComboBox item in the list on startup

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

**UPDATE 1**

It's not about  'select nTH item on startup'... it's more like select THE ITEM that is sitting there defined as  as the initial item and get the combo box updated. I need to set ItemsSource as CompositeCollection where one of the items is defined as specified (doesn't have to be item 0) and set the mentioned item selected on start up. The fact of Binding set to Content of the item plays crucial role in here. The code below just demonstrates an example application.

**END OF UPDATE 1**

I've encountered a small issue that I hope I could get solution for in here. I've a combo box and I'd like to initialize it with particular item selected on startup. The problem is that when I start application control is empty and get's its value on the first open. I've managed to extract the problematic code to the simplest form possible (exclude as many variables as I could) and it looks as follows

XAML code for the window

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:loc ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Key="toSelectInitially" Content="{Binding Path=ActiveItem,   Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0"
              Height="30">
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Path=ActiveItem, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="AAA"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="BBB"/>
            </x:Array>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>

    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{StaticResource ResourceKey=toSelectInitially}"
              Height="30" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded">
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="toSelectInitially"/> 
                <ComboBoxItem Content="AAA"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="BBB"/>
            </x:Array>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>

    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ActiveItem, Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectedValuePath="Content"
              Height="30">
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Path=ActiveItem, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="AAA"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="BBB"/>
            </x:Array>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>

</StackPanel>


</Window>
```

Code behind :

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new VMSimple();
    }
}
}
```

Simple ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
class VMSimple : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public VMSimple()
    {
        ActiveItem = string.Concat("Active Item : ", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }

    private string mActiveItem;
    public string ActiveItem
    {
        get { return mActiveItem; }
        private set
        {
            if (Equals(mActiveItem, value)) return;
            mActiveItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ActiveItem");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
}
```

I've tried to make the code copy-paste-work.

Apparently all of the approaches behave the same (selected value, index, item). Problem goes away if I set list as Items instead of ItemsSource it works but this is not an option. Keep in mind that this is simplified presentation of more complex code where i try to use CompositeCollection but I've replaced it with array to check if this is not causing the problem.

Comment: Do you want the first item to be selected by default?

Comment: Yes, I want this particular item to be selected. The behavior is that content of combo box gets updated once i open it for the first time i start the app.

Comment: Ok I see that you've change the title - I want to select THE item - in my sample code it is item 0 BUT it can be any index, value etc. The concept matters - I get item selected (it's selected as property, and if I check SelectedItem it's correct value) BUT the content of combo box doesn't get updated until I open it ....

Comment: HINT : Seems like binding set on Content matters... if I debug it and hook up do Loaded event on any of the combo box than get SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem and check on Contents is claims Null but if I open it the value changes (binding gets resolved) I might need to play with binding expression there ....

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete example of how i set the first combobox item:

**XAML**

```
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
 public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<string> m_ComboItems= new List<string>();
    private string m_SelectedItem;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        m_ComboItems.Add("AA");
        m_ComboItems.Add("BB");
        m_ComboItems.Add("CC");
        this.SelectedItem = m_ComboItems.First<string>();
    }

    public List<string> ComboItems
    {
        get { return m_ComboItems;}            
    }

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return m_SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            m_SelectedItem = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

If you want to change the selectedItem to something other than the first item in the list then you will need to set the SelectedItem to the object in the list e.g. SelectedItem=m_ComboItems[1] will put "BB" as the selected item.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the suggestion. The problem is that I want to use CompositeCollection and I don't want to bind to one list only. There is a fixed item I want to select at the beginning. So this doesn't solve my particular issue but thank you :)

Comment: Additionally, Values AA, BB are not provided by the same list in this case (are of different type) I know I could get more generic list (of object) and have data template taking care of displaying particular items, but my goal is not to provide things like separator from the view model. I want VM to provide functionalities and view to take care of displaying these in any shape or form :)

Comment: Hi, out of curiosity, is there any particular reason why you want to use a CompositeCollection?

Comment: Because I don't want to provide full menu content view information is the model. I know i could do that but I want the View to decide how to present commands,separators etc. I have 'recent items' list provided by the view model.model provides ClearList command, activeItem object (that is not part of the list). I wanted to make viewModel as abstract as possible. Than in the view I represent all of it as a combobox with Active Item as first item, list of recent items , separator and clear all command item.It's not unsolvable, it's just me liking it this way.It doesn't work and I want to know why

Answer (score 2):

In case you want your first item to be selected as soon as the itemSource get initialized for your combobox, set the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to true for your combobox like this -

```
<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

Comment: Hi, Tried this one, doesn't seem to solve the issue. Behavior is same in both True, False and Null values.